# Running a function on init in app.component.ts

Tags: angular, typescript

This might be a really stupid question, but I've noticed that the `<app-root>` in angular does not implement OnInit like all other components. Say I wanted to put a simple `console.log('Hello World')` in for a example and I wanted that to show every time the app-root was loaded (stupid I know but simple enough for this example), where in the code structure would I do this and does it need a special function name (eg. `ngOnInit()`)? Or is the whole point of angular for this to be nothing more than just a wrapper that initialises other components.

Here's the code in it basic format as the Angular CLI installs it:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

}
```

Comment: Make `AppComponent` implement `OnInit`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes you can add it just like the other components:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log();
  }

}
```

Also, it's not that you shouldn't do it. Like anything else, there should be a reason. It just depends on what you are trying to do. That's what more accurately would determine whether or not what you are trying to do is correct/incorrect or good practice/bad practice*

Comment: Thanks - I'm actually using it for an API call and I'll be honest I'm not 100% sure if that's good practice or it would be better to take it out and move it to another component.

Comment: Personally, I don't think it is good practice to make API calls in the App component

Comment: @AnthonyAgbator , what would be your approach ? I also am loading all app data in ngOnInit of app component which I agree might not be optimal

Comment: @Ayush The App component is the app root and should not be used for complex logic apart from bootstrapping the app itself.